# Batch must implement method: void Database.Batchable<AI_EACUserConnectedBatch.EAC>.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List<AI_EACUserConnectedBatch.EA

Tags: apex

```
public class AI_EACUserConnectedBatch implements Database.Batchable<EAC> {
    String ActiveConnStatus = 'ACTIVE';
    private class EAC{
        public Map<Id, Boolean> usermap;
        public Map<Id,String> eacconfigmap;
    }

    public EAC[] start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        EAC[] allUserAndEACConfigRecords = new EAC[0];
        allUserAndEACConfigRecords.usermap = new Map<Id,Boolean>([SELECT Id, EAC_Connected_User__c FROM User where EAC_Connected_User__c = true]);
        List<ActivityUsrConnectionStatus> ulist = [Select Id,userid,ConnectivityStatus from ActivityUsrConnectionStatus];
        
        if(!ulist.isEmpty()){
            for(ActivityUsrConnectionStatus logd : ulist){
                (allUserAndEACConfigRecords.eacconfigmap).put(logd.UserId,logd.ConnectivityStatus);
            }
        }        
        
        return allUserAndEACConfigRecords;
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,EAC allUserAndEACConfigRecords){
        /*for (EAC rec : allUserAndEACConfigRecords) {
            // Do something
        }*/
   
        Map<Id,String> UsrConnectedStatus = new Map<Id,String>(allUserAndEACConfigRecords.eacconfigmap);
        Map<ID, Boolean> ActiveUsrList = new Map<ID, Boolean>(allUserAndEACConfigRecords.usermap);
        Set<ID> UserObjId = new Set<ID>(ActiveUsrList.keySet());
        Set<ID> AUC_UserId = new Set<ID>(UsrConnectedStatus.keySet());
        Set<ID> result = AUC_UserId.clone();
        
        if(!UserObjId.isEmpty()){
            UserObjId.removeall(AUC_UserId);
            if(!result.isEmpty()){
                result.addAll(UserObjId);
            }    
        }    
        
        List<User> userListnew = new List<User>();
        if(!result.isEmpty()){
            for (Id userID : result){
                if( !AUC_UserId.isEmpty() && AUC_UserId.contains(userID) )
                {
                    if(UsrConnectedStatus.get(userID) == ActiveConnStatus){
                        userListnew.add(new User(id = userID,EAC_Connected_User__c = true));
                    }
                    else {
                        userListnew.add(new User(id = userID,EAC_Connected_User__c = false));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    userListnew.add(new User(id = userID,EAC_Connected_User__c = false));
                }
            }
        }   
        if(!userListnew.IsEmpty()){ 
            try{
                database.update(userListnew,false);
            } 
            catch(DmlException ex ){}
        }     
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){ 

    }    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This is a Questions and Answers site. I see a code dump, but I do not see a question. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/383861/edit) your post to ask a specific question that you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,EAC allUserAndEACConfigRecords){
```

Should be a List parameter:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, EAC[] allUserAndEACConfigRecords){
```

Or:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<EAC> allUserAndEACConfigRecords){
```